# Belkzen Hold 'Warcat of Rull' Space/Reach?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, creature-size

In the Paizo Pathfinder "Belkzen, Hold of the Orc Hordes" supplement, the new monster 'Warcat of Rull' is listed as a size Huge creature, with a Space of 15' and a Reach of 15'. It is a quadruped, so it would qualify as a Huge (Long) creature.

Normally, according to the RaW, a size Huge (Long) creature has a Space 15' and Reach 10' (Only a Huge (Tall) creature would have Reach 15'), so is this correct? (It's perhaps also worth noting they did the same thing with the 'Bull of Zagresh' in the same supplement, giving it Space/Reach both of 15')

There's a huge tactical advantage to a creature that is already so large and commanding so much battlefield space to also have that kind of reach...it would be threatening an area 45' across! If anyone has come across an official ruling on this issue, I'd be much obliged.

Comment: The Huge(Long) reach of 10' is a default, there are plenty of exceptions.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. I assume you've already searched the Paizo messageboards for information about this creature and come up empty, correct? With that in mind, would, for example, finding similar creatures of equivalent size and reach "prove" the warcat's statistics accurate, or is developer input the only proof of accuracy that's acceptable? No matter what, though, thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 1):

**Related:** [Where do I find the “Specific beats general” rule?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62373/where-do-i-find-the-specific-beats-general-rule)

Though as the top answer to this post shows that (at least at the time of its posting) there is no official text for this rule, the answer itself provides reasoning for why such a rule might be used in pathfinder. Using this line of thought for a ruling, the specific:

> 'Warcat of Rull' is listed as a size Huge creature, with a Space of
>   15' and a Reach of 15'

... would overrule the general:

> according to the RaW, a size Huge (Long) creature has a Space 15' and
>   Reach 10'

Like @KRyan I was unable to find official Paizo text where this rule is made official, so feel free to use any DM fiat you would like when determining this, I would note that, while on one hand it might be a typo, on the other hand it may be written-as-intended for an increased degree of difficulty.

Edit: I should also qualify that my previous pathfinder group ran this supplement with no changes last fall, our DM possibly using the above rule for the judgement (we were not informed of any changes to the text).