# Clothier's Closet via Shadow Conjuration ... Any wrinkles?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

Clothier's Closet = Spell on pg. 94, Magic of Eberron
Shadow Conjuration = Spell on pg. 276, PHB

---

If my wizard mimicked Clothier's Closet via a Shadow Conjuration spell, would my wizard and my 3 party-mates all be able to benefit from having "permanent" access to the remaining clothes?

Do we also run the risk of having the conjured support rod be only 20% real or some-such?

My group and I have lots of theories about how this spell will ultimately work and we'd love some expert outside views to help solidify a final position.  And yes, we all are aware that the Shadow Conj/Evoc spells are some of the most controversial ones in 3.5 and PF. Any other quirks or idiosyncracies about this specific spell being  mimicked would be welcome to hear as well.  Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great first question. Be sure to take the [tour]. Also, +1 just for the pun in the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [The Emperor's New Clothes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Clothes), v2.0

*Clothier's closet*, is a 2nd level Conjuration(creation) spell, whose description says:

> ...The conjured clothing is normal in all respects and does not radiate magic. Even after the duration elapses and the rod and hangers [the clothes are conjured on] disappear, the clothes remain.

So they persist indefinitely as (20% real) normal clothes. The spell says that they do not radiate magic, so they don't (that's a bit of '[specific trumps general](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62373)').

The SRD version of [*shadow conjuration*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shadow-conjuration) regarding objects says:

> You use material from the Plane of Shadow to shape quasi-real illusions of one or more ...objects[.] Shadow conjuration can mimic any sorcerer or wizard ...conjuration (creation) spell of 3rd level or lower.

> Shadow conjurations are actually one-fifth (20%) as strong as the real things, though creatures who believe the shadow conjurations to be real are affected by them at full strength.

> Any creature that interacts with the conjured object, force, or creature can make a Will save to recognize its true nature.

> A creature that succeeds on its save sees the shadow conjurations as transparent images superimposed on vague, shadowy forms.

> ...any effect created by shadow conjuration allows spell resistance, even if the spell it is simulating does not. Shadow objects or substances have normal effects except against those who disbelieve them...Against disbelievers, they are 20% likely to work.

> Objects automatically succeed on their Will saves against this spell.

So, *clothier's closet*, being a 2nd level Conjuration(Creation) spell, obviously qualifies for being simulated by the *shadow conjuration* spell. The clothes have 20% of normal hit points, and as DM, I'd rule hardness as well (which for most cloth should be 0 anyway). A creature trying to tear them off a character or otherwise damage them would have an easier time of it as they have 80% fewer HP.

If you're wearing the clothes, and someone looks too hard at your outfit or touches it, they get a save to know it's not real. So anyone making the save can see they're not real.

Creatures with [spell resistance](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#when-spell-resistance-applies), are impacted as normal by the spell, as it does not directly impact them. The pertinent rules regarding spell resistance here are:

> Magic actually has to be working for spell resistance to apply. Spells that have instantaneous durations but lasting results aren’t subject to spell resistance unless the resistant creature is exposed to the spell the instant it is cast...
>
> Spell resistance does not apply if an effect fools the creature’s senses or reveals something about the creature...
>
> Against an ongoing spell that has already been cast, a failed check against spell resistance allows the resistant creature to ignore any effect the spell might have. The magic continues to affect others normally...
>
> **Illusion:** These spells are almost never subject to spell resistance. Illusions that entail a direct attack are exceptions.

As an object, the warrior's sword will always cut these illusory clothes easier than normal clothes, since it gets a save as an [attended object](http://dndsrd.net/carryingAndExploration.html#object-saving-throws), which it automatically succeeds at, and thus it ignores 80% of any hardness the clothes might have, and they have 80% lower HP.

---

Crai's comment regarding [clothes](http://dndsrd.net/goodsAndServices.html#clothing), that have game effects recalled that some clothes are useful as well as decorative:

Artisan’s Outfit has pockets, but they are not a special effect; the only issue is the clothing's reduced HP.

Cleric’s Vestments have no listed effects.

Cold Weather Outfit the bonus to saving throws could be lessened from +5 to +1, as weather is an object. However, weather is unattended, so never makes saving throws perhaps just leave it.

Courtier’s Outfit does *not* include the 50 gp of jewelry, so you *still* look like an out-of-place commoner without it.

Entertainer’s Outfit is what this spell might be 'perfect' for. Though 25% of folks looking at the outfit instead of the entertainer will then focus again on the entertainer (upon making their saving throw).

Explorer’s Outfit: also has pockets, but they are not a special effect; the only issue is the clothing's reduced HP.

Monk’s Outfit sash-ropes are 80% weaker and also completely fail to affect *attended* objects 80% of the time and fail versus creatures ~20% of the time.

Noble’s Outfit, like the courtier's outfit, also has no signet ring or jewelry; without them you'd still not fit among other nobles.

Scholar’s and Traveler’s Outfits are actually pretty simple, being good clothes plus cap and hood.

---

Regarding the impact of free clothes on the economy, consider that *shadow conjuration* is a 4th level spell, and its save DC is often 16.

So 25% (5 of 20) average folks examining or touching the clothes will know they're fake. Higher wisdom or higher level folks will have a better chance to see that they're false.

Additionally, word of mouth will have everyone looking for false clothes once it's known that these false clothes exist, and that 25% can communicate their success to others, granting a +4 bonus to disbelieve for those around them.

So, if overused they'll eventually be hard to sell, and even without overuse, they're not terribly useful.

Comment: Being immediately reminded of the drow armor in AD&D that dissolved in sunlight, would this particular combination of shadow magic and fabrication spells creates objects that are subject to damage from prolonged exposure to sunlight? Or just the reduced HP?

Comment: @Tristian There's no mention of sun damage to normal materials, but if the spell mimicked such materials, then they'd be 80% weaker, so usually fail faster.

Comment: I might be tempted to rule that because "any effect created by *shadow conjuration* allows spell resistance, even if the spell it is simulating does not" that the clothing remains an effect created by the spell therefore magical therefore the clothes capable of being dispelled when handled by a creature with a SR. (That's largely because I *hate* the spell *clothier's closet*, and I'm always tempted to make a house rule changing the spell to the transmutation school and make everyone cast it as if he had a Mark of Hospitality.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan It's merely a *very* limited version of *true creation* that only makes clothing.

Comment: I see the spell more it as a low level version of *fabricate* that turns a 100-gp gem into clothes… and that, if you can dodge that component like with a *boon trap of clothier's closet*, has unimaginably goofy effects on the campaign.  The spell makes the worldbuilding part of my brain hurt is all.

Comment: Thanks to Chemus and the others for all your insights.  Also to note, some of mimicked outfits have game mechanic components to them.  Like the Cold Weather Outfit which grants the wearer a +5 to FORT saves against exposure maladies from cold weather.  It's assumed the wearers of such clothes will "believe" they're real in order to benefit from them. But yeah, I agree with HICC ... this combo is a macroeconomic game-wrecker...

Comment: @Crai The weather might be considered to be an object, thus automatically making the bonuses 80% lower (+1 Fort vs cold, etc). Regarding economics: perhaps. Who'll wear clothes that roughly 20%+ percent of folks might see through (usually 17 will save) especially wise and leveled folks, and whose bonuses versus weather, etc are greatly diminished? In fact, 20%+ of buyers will, upon examining the clothes discover their nature, and the clothes would 'fall' off the racks 80% of the time.

Comment: Whoops, that save is 16, so 25%+ see through the clothes.

Comment: The pockets and things working only 20% of the time is a real stretch. Not convinced there.

Comment: @KRyan Which is why I have another [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103087/ "Can an object's attendant forgo its saving throw?") on the stack. Perhaps I ought not have added the pockets issue without resolving it first.

Comment: They don't see through the clothes when they succeed, they see you clothed in 'vague shadowy form' s (+transparent images on top of that).  Important difference.

Comment: I don't even buy that the quasi-reality of the spell effect extends that far or in that fashion. If nothing else, the answer would be improved by spending some time establishing that; currently it seems implicitly assumed.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer Yes, I used perhaps too much license to say 'see through'.

Comment: @KRyan I've added the support for my pockets claim in:  "Shadow objects or substances have normal effects except against those who disbelieve them.

Against disbelievers, they are 20% likely to work." and the objects automatically make saving throws versus *shadow conjuration*, and attended objects get a save with their attendant's bonuses. It's whether the attendant can forgo the save that's the pith of the other question