# Can a bag of holding be used to dispose of evil artifacts?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, artifacts

According to the description of Bag Of Holding

> If a bag of holding is overloaded, or if sharp objects pierce it (from inside or outside), the bag immediately ruptures and is ruined, and all contents are lost forever.

Does this mean that it is possible to place a doomsday device or an evil magical artifact in the bag of holding before intentionally rupturing it to destroy those things?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This GM would allow a [*discern location*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/discern-location/) effect or similar effect to locate a ripped *bag*'s contents individually despite those contents being—supposedly—lost forever, but this player wouldn't storm out of another GM's campaign if that GM ruled that was impossible. Rest assured, though, that in such a GM's campaign, this player would—could his PC afford them—invest in a few extra *bags of holding* for disposing of artifacts of great evil and corpses of defeated villains!

To be clear, this GM would allow the *discern location* effect to work because descriptions like this often appear to this reader to be written in isolation, without regard to the rest of the game, forcing the GM to make decisions about the description's *actual* meaning. That is, while this GM totally approves of PCs spending 2,500 gp on a [*bag of holding*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding/) so that it can be employed as single-use garbage disposal, this GM interprets the *bag*'s description to mean that if the *bag* is stuffed too full or poked with a longsword or whatever then the *bag*'s contents are forever lost *if the* bag of holding *is what's being relied on to retrieve those contents.*

Lots of things in *Pathfinder* and its antecedent *D&D 3.5e* make (some would say *grandiose*) claims that seem to consider *nothing* beyond their own descriptions. For example, the spell [*contagion*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contagion/) says that the spell's subject (if the subject fails a saving throw and the caster overcomes the subject's SR) contracts a disease, but I've never heard of a GM ruling that a subject that is *immune* to disease—like the typical [level 3 paladin](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/#TOC-Divine-Health-Ex-)—contracts a disease *anyway* because the *contagion* spell *says* the subject contracts a disease! Similarly, a level 20 [fighter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter/archetypes/icosa-entertainment-llc/pugilist-fighter-archetype/) will laugh at the "great ability in unarmed combat" that's conferred upon her by a [*monk's robe*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/robe-monk-s/) because that ability is like that of a level 5 monk—seriously, *great ability in unarmed combat* is by its nature a relative and context-dependent description.

The game is too vast to list *every* exception—the *contagion* spell won't bother saying that the subject contracts the disease *unless the subject's immune to diseases*, for instance, nor will the *monk's robe* say that it confers great ability in unarmed combat *unless you're already aces at the punching*—, leaving it up to the reader to determine if each absolute statement is an *actual* absolute or if exceptions still apply.<sup>1</sup>

Thus even a ripped *bag of holding*'s description of its contents being *lost forever* needn't be an airtight absolute. The spell [*discern location*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/discern-location/) really *can* find *any* object if the caster's first touched the object, and the *bag*'s description of its ability to *lose* things seems to this reader *as* specific as the spell's description of its ability to *find* things! This GM would go ahead and make the call and let the *discern location* effect work, *lost forever* usually being terrible for storytelling anyway.

So ask your GM how absolute *lost forever* is… and be sure to mention the spell *discern location*.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Usually determining which exceptions apply is done *via* determining which effect is more specific (i.e. the [specific-beats-general rule](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62373/8610) that's the crux of exception-based game design). However, in many cases—like this one—determining *what* exactly *is* more specific is an exercise in futility.

Comment: In my headcanon the contents of a damaged bag of holding are spilled in the Maelstrom in a random place, which is often equivalent to "lost forever" unless you *really* want to find them.

Comment: +1 for consistently referring to yourself in two different third persons (as well as for getting the idea right).

Answer (score 12):

As written, yes.

But in practice, artifacts often break the rules and surviving this kind of mishap would be something I expect if the plot hinges on the artifact’s existence and the impossibility of destroying it. *The Lord of the Rings* would have made a pretty poor story if the One Ring could have been destroyed, and so too might your campaign, so don’t be surprised if the GM nixes it.

Comment: it might be worth noting, the ruling says the contents are lost, not destroyed. if the artifacts existence is the threat, this would render it un-destroyable.  if its use is the threat, it might render it unusable. But such power artifacts have a tendency to find a user.

Comment: @MichaelGorman I mean, again as written, we have “lost forever,” and the difference between “lost forever” and “destroyed” is kind of academic.

Comment: @KRyan depends on the artifact. In the case of the One Ring, for instance, Sauron's power was bound up with its existence, even when it was out of his possession. "Destroyed" was very much worse for him than "lost forever".