# What happens to objects halfway inside the bag when it gets ruptured?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

According to the official pathfinder rules:

> If a bag of holding is overloaded, or if sharp objects pierce it (from inside or outside), the bag immediately ruptures and is ruined, and all contents are lost forever.

If I were to take a knife and pierce the bag from the inside, would my hand get amputated by the bag rupturing or would it be fine since I'm not completely in the bag?

Comment: Hi Masterhaend, and welcome to the site. Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep you're welcome to join us in [chat]. By that artifact reference do you mean one you can't let go of, or one you can just toss in freely?

Comment: Artifacts have their own destruction rules specific to each artifact and apparently most of them can only destroyed by following those rules, e.g. a Philosopher's Stone is destroyed "by being placed in the heel of a titan’s boot for at least 1 entire week."

Comment: Ok. Since that's a different question, you should ask it separately -- I've removed that part of this question. Whether anything in the entrance of the bag gets severed, and whether you can eliminate an artifact by putting it in the bag and puncturing it, both revolve around the bag of holding but are different matters entirely, so we'd prefer them separate so that users with only an answer to one but not both can each (separately) provide you the best answers you can get. You can access the previous revision by clicking the "edited X time ago" link in the bottom center of your post.

Comment: Related to that other question: [Can a bag of holding be used to dispose of evil artifacts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/114214/1204)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## There's no official answer…

Ask the GM what happens if a creature sticks its arm in a [*bag of holding*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding/) and then pokes the *bag* with a sword until the *bag* rips. That's the best—and, really, only—way to find out what'll happen in a specific campaign.

#### …However, the task described is impossible in this GM's campaigns

In this GM's campaigns a creature or object is *either* on one plane *or* on another plane and *not* simultaneously on *two* planes. Because a *bag of holding* is less like an actual bag and more like a portable portal to another plane, a creature can take either a move action or a full-round action to retrieve an item from the *bag*, or a creature can take a move action to stow an item in the *bag*. A creature can't, in this GM's campaigns, opt to stick only its arm in the *bag* and leave his arm there while he goes about his day anymore than a creature could store just the bottom quarter of a tall tree within a *bag* and leave the top of the tree hanging out of the *bag*. Instead, the *either* the creature puts something all the way in *or* the thing doesn't go in at all, and, likewise, *either* the creature enters the *bag* completely *or* the creature doesn't enter it at all.

While this GM admits that this is a kind of no fun ruling that eliminates a lot of *bag of holding* shenanigans, this ruling also means the GM doesn't have to figure out what happens if, for example, the PCs go to a fast time trait plane and have their golem walk around with the PCs in a *bag of holding* while only the PCs' heads are sticking out so that their *heads* age and not the rest of their bodies (so that they can benefit from the increased *mental* ability scores that come from aging but not suffer the lowered *physical* ability scores due to aging… obviously). Not having to worry about stuff like that makes this GM's life easier.