# Oracle's Curse and Handy Haversack

Tags: pathfinder-1e, curses, oracle

Would a Handy Haversack alleviate a Haunted Oracle's [curse](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#HauntedFAQ)?

> Retrieving any stored item from your gear requires a standard action, unless it would normally take longer. Any item you drop lands 10 feet away from you in a random direction. Add mage hand and ghost sound to your list of spells known.

Comment: Few words about the curse would make this question better. We shouldn't have to click links to get a grasp on what you're talking about.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description of the [*handy haversack*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-handy-haversack/) covers how the item works for the user if nothing about the user specifically changes how the *haversack* works. For average folks, "[r]etrieving any specific item from a *[handy] haversack* is a move action, but [doing so] does not provoke the attacks of opportunity that retrieving a stored item usually does."

However, a creature with the curse [haunted](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Oracle/oracle-curses/#HauntedFAQ) isn't average. For such a creature "[r]etrieving any stored item from your gear requires a standard action, unless it would normally take longer." This makes it so the specific rules of the haunted curse override the general way in which the *handy haversack* functions. (For more about exception-based design in *Pathfinder* see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62373/8610).)

For the *handy haversack* to function normally when used by the cursed creature, the *haversack*'s description would have to say it was an exception to the haunted curse.

Comment: I tend to agree with this interpretation. However, both the Handy Haversack and the curse could both be read as more-specific than the other (when "this specific character" retrieves and item vs. from "this specific bag"); I think the answer could be bolstered by mentioning the incongruity of a relatively cheap, standard piece of adventuring gear negating a class drawback, especially when most (all?) of the other curses' drawbacks are significantly more difficult to work around (if possible at all).

Comment: @minnmass I considered that as a possibility, but I think the *haversack* is the generalest of cases here: the *haversack* functions like it says it functions for everyone *then* exceptions are made, and one of those exceptions would be the haunted curse. Maybe? Also, yeah, it would be a pretty inexpensive almost-escape from an otherwise nasty curse. (It still wouldn't help with everything—I briefly played a haunted oracle who wielded a longspear, and being unable to drop the longspear and pick it up again immediately came up surprisingly often!)